# Random Number input 425500

Tags: c++

I am working on an array program, for resorting an array after deleting the duplicates.

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>

 using namespace std;

 int main(){

int x;
int y;
int z;
int ArrayLength;
int tempArrayValue;

//prompt for array length
cout << "How many numbers do you want the array to be?" << endl;
cin >> ArrayLength;

//initialize array
int D[ArrayLength];

//Put values into each element of the array
for (int a = 0; a < ArrayLength; a++)
{
    cout << "Enter in Values." <<endl;
    cin >> tempArrayValue;
    D[a] = tempArrayValue;
    cout << endl;
}

//compare each element
for (int x = 0; x < ArrayLength; x++) 
{

    for (int y = x + 1; y < ArrayLength; y++)
    {
             if (D[x] == D[y])  
             {
                D[y] = 0;   
             }    

            //system("PAUSE");

    for (z = 0; z < ArrayLength; z++)
        {
        if (D[z] == 0)
            {
                D[z] = D[z+1];  
                D[z+1] = 0;
                //cout << D[z];     
            }
        }



    }   


}
cout << D[0] << endl << D[1] << endl << D[2] << endl << D[3] << endl << D[4] <<endl << D[5] <<endl;
 }
```

I get the output:

```
How many numbers do you want the array to be?
6
Enter in Values.
1

Enter in Values.
1

Enter in Values.
2

Enter in Values.
9

Enter in Values.
4

Enter in Values.
9

1
2
9
4
4255009
0
```

What puzzles me is: what the heck is that big number doing there?  I figure that the nine is probably the last number that I entered, and it worked fine replacing the first one, but the second duplicate there is an issue.  I theorize it might be something with the compiler, what are some other compilers, I'm using dev-c++ right now.

Comment: Note that unless you really need to do this on your own (e.g., for homework) you'd probably be better off looking up `std::unique` instead.

Answer (score 1):

`D[z+1]` can access past the end of the allocated array, resulting in Undefined Behavior.

Also, declaring `int D[ArrayLength]` (a variable length array) is a non-standard extension supported by some compilers and will not compile everywhere.  You should use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: Couldn't I just change the declaration of the array to int D[ArrayLength + 1]?  To give it that spot to compare with?

Comment: @Thomas You could, but what value would you initially put there?

Comment: 0, all it needs is the spot to compare with, right?  Undefined behavior is caused because I reached past the end of the array, all a vector would do would extend the array to what is needed right?

Comment: I'm working on this for fun so I'll learn more about vectors before I spend too much more time into this, thanks for the info.

Comment: @Thomas Just think about what it means (what your program is doing) when it tries to access that last element...

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your requirements you can benefit from a few things.

As @1201ProgramAlarm stated you are indexing past the end of an array, which is undefined behavior, and you are seeing a *garbage value* as a result of that behavior.

You are redefining both `x` and `y` within your `for` loops. You should declare variables where and right before you need them. This will help to keep track of things.

As others have said there are C++ tools that can do what you are asking for. Namely, `std::set` will allow you to maintain a container with unique values.

You should probably not use a *raw array* unless you absolutely need to. If you are unsure whether or not you "*need to*" use `std::vector`.

If your goal is to use **C++**, then you should use it and not miss out on its features.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <vector>

void delete_duplicates(std::vector<int>& A)
{
    // delete the duplicates in A
}

void insertion_sort(std::vector<int>& A)
{
    // sort by insertion, selection, or exchange
}

std::vector<int> get_user_values()
{
    // require user input as before
    // with a small amount of input
    // you can just return a copy of
    // a vector
    std::vector<int> a_copy_of_a_vector;
    return a_copy_of_a_vector;
}

void display_results(const std::vector<int>& A)
{
    for (auto& elem : A)
        std::cout << elem << " ";
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

According to your question you would like to *sort* and *delete duplicates*. You will find it worth your time to break those tasks into 
functions.

Now if something goes wrong in your code you may have a better idea of where to go looking.

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> user_values = get_user_values();
    insertion_sort(user_values);

    // You may find it easier to delete
    // duplicates from a sorted list.
    delete_duplicates(user_values);

    return 0;
}
```